# How to extract specific substring from an expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text:

```
Units Currently On Bed List
[total beds=0]
Number Of Beds Unit Interval Select All
```

The number after '=' is dynamic and subject to change. How can I extract the number in java using regex?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I reformatted your question to be more easily readable. However, your question is still missing some crucial information: What have you tried so far? What is your error and what exactly are you struggling with? Right now this question is too broad and SO does not aim to provide tutorials on demand. Please refer to the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for a detailed tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "*number after = is dynamic and subject to change.*", then for your example data you could for example capture the number in a group:

[`\[.+?=(\d+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/f97nf2/1)

- Match a `\[`
- Match any character one or more times non greedy `.+?`
- Match an equal sign `=`
- Capture 1 or more digits `(\d+)`
- Match a `\]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sute using regex but this is one way :

```
int first = str.indexOf('=') +1;
int last = str.lastIndexOf(']');

String nbr = str.subString(first,last );
int number = Integer.parseInt(nbr);
```